# Workers in spring batch are failing with "IllegalStateException: AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext has been closed already"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Workers are failing after successful processing with exception

{"@timestamp":"2022-12-19T12:45:43.89+05:30","level":"ERROR","thread":"main","logger":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","message":"Application run failed","stack_trace":["java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2a225dd7 has been closed already","    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.assertBeanFactoryActive(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1138)","    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1153)","    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.getTargetBean(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:371)","    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:336)","    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:229)","    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:166)","    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)","    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)","    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)","    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421)","    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378)","    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.ready(EventPublishingRunListener.java:114)","    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$ready$6(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:82)","    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)","    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)","    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)","    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.ready(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:82)","    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323)","    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)","    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)","    at com.example.package.ExampleBatchMainA.main(ExampleBatchMainA.java:47)","    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)","    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)","    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)","    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)","    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)","    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)","    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)","    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:467)"]}

Spring Boot Version :  2.7.5
spring-cloud-task-core : 2.4.4
Spring-Batch-Core : 4.3.7

workers to exit successfully without the exception.

Comment: After changing version of spring-cloud-task-core : 2.4.4 to 2.1.1RELEASE it is working without throwing that exception